# Reproducing the elements of an array practically in Raku

Tags: raku

How to reproduce each element of an array **x** times?

For instance`for my @a=<blu red>;` and **x=5**, the result should look like

`(blu blu blu blu blu red red red red red)`

I've come up with this

```
say flat map { ($_, $_, $_, $_, $_) }, @a;
```

but of course for arbitrary values of x, it's not practical.

How to do it practically? Thank you.

Comment: Try this: `my @b = @a.map({ $_ xx $x }).flat`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the [infix xx](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#infix_xx) operator like this:

```
my @a=<blu red>;
my $x = 5;
my @b = @a.map({ $_ xx $x }).flat;
say @b;
```

**Output**:

```
[blu blu blu blu blu red red red red red]
```

**Edit**:

.. or simply use [`flatmap`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/flatmap) (though the documentation says the use of `flatmap` it is discouraged)

```
my @b = @a.flatmap({ $_ xx $x });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I didn't that operator. The `flatmap` looks cool as well.

Comment: Personally I'd prefer to use the Slip (`|`):
`my @a=<blu red>;
my $x = 5;
my @b = @a.map: { slip $_ xx $x };
say @b;`

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen I didn't know about the `slip` It's as good as the flatmap method. Good to know. Thanks.

Comment: @LarsMalmsteen and it will perform better, as `map` already checks for `Slip`s being returned by the block in the `map`, and processes them directly.  Rather than having `flat` doing post-processing.